# Fluid width and fixed with columns with border in between

Tags: html, css, layout, jsfiddle

I have fluid width left column and a fixed width right column. I need a border in between them that is the height of the tallest column.

Here is the simplified layout of what I have:

```
.left {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.left-inner {
    margin-right: 275px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    border-right: 2px dotted #47718D;
}   
.right {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 30px;
    width: 275px;
    margin-left: -275px;
}
<div class="left">
    <div class="left-inner">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
    Sidebar
</div>
```

Here's a more detailed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/meaLh

As you can see the border stops where the content of the left column stops. Both of the columns are variable height so sometimes the left column will be longer than the right. How do I get these to be equal so I can have the border go all the way down?

Comment: Am not understanding that how you are expecting your layout to be, did you saw the fiddle?

Comment: try instead float to use display:table/table-cell and right-border on first-child

Comment: @Mr.Alien I have rephrased the last paragraph

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1260px;
}
.left {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.left-inner {
    margin-right: 275px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
.right {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 30px;
    width: 275px;
    margin-left: -275px;
    border-left: 2px dotted #47718D;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that sometimes the left column will be longer than the right column and sometimes the other way round as they hold dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

The border stops where the content of the left column stops because the border attribute was applied to the left column.Similarly a border applied to the right column will stop where the content of the right column stops.Now if you want the border to go below the content, you can use some padding at the bottom of the columns. You may also use a third column between the left and the right column with a really small width and apply a min-height, and border to it.

Comment: These columns have dynamic content so sometimes left is longer and sometimes right is longer. These solutions will only work if I know the exact height right?